# Replacing multiple occurrences of substring in Red language

Tags: string, stack-overflow, rebol, red

I am trying to have a function that replaces multiple occurrences of `oripart` to `newpart` in the sent string:

```
strReplace: func [str [string!] oripart [string!] newpart [string!]][
        if find str oripart [   
            change find str oripart newpart
            strReplace str oripart newpart ]  ; recursion to change more occurrences; 
        str ]

print strReplace "this is a short line" "short" "small"
print strReplace "this is a short line" "this" "THIS"
print strReplace "this is a short line" "line" "LINE"
print strReplace "this is a long line" "short" "small"
print strReplace "this is a short short line" "short" "small"
```

I am using recursion to remove multiple occurrences. It works all right for a single test line. However, it is producing stack overflow if I am testing above code. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you do not use just **replace** or **replace/all**

`replace/all oristr oripart newpart`

Your trial blows up because you change e.g. **"this"** to **"THIS"** and Red same as Rebol is mostly case insensitive, if you do not demand explicitly strict or case. So it recurses and recurses.

```
>> "this" = "THIS"
== true
>>  "this" == "THIS" 
== false
>> find "this"  "THIS"
== "this"
```

If you really want to use your own **strReplace** you should use **find/case**

```
>> find/case "this"  "THIS"
== none
```

There is one more solution to your problem; recurse at a position after the change as in

```
    strReplace: func [
        str [string!] oripart [string!] newpart [string!]
    ][
        if find str oripart [   
            str: change find str oripart newpart
            strReplace str oripart newpart   ; recursion to change more occurrences; 
        ]
        head str 
    ]
```

Comment: Yes, find/case was the real issue.

Comment: Use **replace/all** instead, as it replaces all occurences